# Is defensive Riki viable?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

Is it viable to use Riki like Reyn was early-game? i.e as an armour tank, a opposed to an agility tank like Dunban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riki *can* be an armour tank, but he's naturally worse at it than the designated tanks. This is mostly because he has no real good way to generate and keep aggro; he only really has Behave for paralysis (less auto-attacks to eat) and You Can Do It for healing (healing a lot of people makes a lot of aggro). And a decent amount of his physical attacks are supposed to be used from the side or behind. It requires a lot of gems wrangling and probably ether art spam for Riki to keep aggro. He does end up being the de facto tank in a full-ether party though.